# Bordered 5-corners CSS element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need to create an element like this:

[image]

5 corners, border and text in `<span>` element. How can I achieve that result? I have only managed to create the normal element with 4 corners.

```css
.pin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 34px;
  min-width: 42px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}
.pin__green {
  background-color: #689f39;
  border: 1px solid #59902b;
}
.pt {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="pin pin__green">
  <span class="pt">
    <span>2</span>
    <span>new</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a single element solution. Basically you use the pseudo-elements `::before` to create the tip (same styles as for your main element but rotated by 45°) and `::after` to hide the left unwanted box-shadow.

Some additional hints: Don't nest `<span>` elements and use `0` instead of `0px` for CSS zero values.

```css
.pin {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  min-width: 42px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 2px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}
.pin-green {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-left: 0 solid;
}
/* the tip */

.pin::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/* hide the left box-shadow */

.pin::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin pin-green">2 new</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**SVG**

This shape is a lot easier to create with svg:
The text element has **tspan** elements instead of span elements

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.greenButtonText {
  font-size: 25px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 110 60" width="60px">
  <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#689f39" fill="#689f39" d="M0,25 25,0 100,0 100,50 25,50z" />
  <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="#92C567" fill="none" d="M0,25 25,0 100,0 100,50 25,50z" />
  <text class="greenButtonText" x="25" y="32">
    <tspan>2</tspan>
    <tspan font-size="20">NEW</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Larger copy:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.greenButtonText {
  font-size: 25px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<!---Copy for display only--->
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 110 60" width="150px">
  <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5" stroke="#689f39" fill="#689f39" d="M0,25 25,0 100,0 100,50 25,50z" />
  <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1" stroke="#92C567" fill="none" d="M0,25 25,0 100,0 100,50 25,50z" />
  <text class="greenButtonText" x="25" y="32">
    <tspan>2</tspan>
    <tspan font-size="20">NEW</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. New skill achieved)

Comment: svg is better suited for complex shapes, yet in your chase the shape is not so complex, but perhaps complex to achieve with css.